# Android In-App Purchase onPurchaseStateChange() not called

Tags: android

I am trying to implement android in-app purchase.
onPurchaseStateChange() is not called while trying to test sample in-app application using static product ids.

How am i supposed to know whether the product has been purchased or not?

Comment: Did you find some answer on this one, I have the same issue. I think the manifest is correct, put the key in from the google play developers page and signed the app with another key. Published everything and my card is being charged, but the metho never called.

Comment: You are welcome to check my answer regarding this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12948238/444324

Answer (score 0):

It seems problem in Manifest properties if you folow right Dev Guide.
Does Market Activity shows?
Check if you mention service and reciever(I think that is) in manifest file.